# Meu menu mobile fica fixo no topo, mas o dropdown segue o scroll dele, o que fazer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou criando um site responsivo manualmente, logo criei 2 menus, um para aparecer no desktop e outro para versão mobile. Esses menus não ficam no topo, e sim cerca de uns 150 pixels de distância. Decidi então criar um script que me permita fixar o menu após o `scroll` alcançar esses `150px;` Segue código

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var menu = $('.menu-geral-desktop');
    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
            $('.menu-geral-desktop').addClass('menu-fixo-desk').fadeIn(500);
            $('.menu-geral-desktop').fadeIn( );
            $('.brand-topo-desk').css('display','block');
            $('.itens-menu-desk').addClass('css-menu-centro-desk');
            $('.menu-geral-mobile').addClass('menu-fixo-desk').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('.menu-geral-desktop').removeClass('menu-fixo-desk'); 
            $('.brand-topo-desk').css('display','none', 500);
            $('.itens-menu-desk').removeClass('css-menu-centro-desk');
            $('.menu-geral-mobile').removeClass('menu-fixo-desk'); 
        };
    };

    document.onscroll = scroll;    
});
```

No desktop está funcionando corretamente, o problema é no menu mobile. O menu em si fica fixo no topo após rolar os 150 pixeis,  no entanto quando abro o dropdown, ao rolar a pagina, as opções rolam junto com o scroll, mesmo o menu em si estando fixo no topo. Deve ser alguma configuração no CSS. Segue a estilização do menu mobile.

```
    .itens-menu-mob{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 00px;
    z-index: 100000!important;
    background-color: rgba(50,151,163,1.00);
    display: none;
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Partes do CSS que podem ser dispensados: float (já que será fixo, não precisa). margin-top (não precisa colocar 00px, coloque apenas 0, sem o px. Quando o valor for 0, o px é dispensável). z-index (teste sem o !important. Acho que irá funcionar e seu código ficará mais limpo). background-color (o valor alpha não precisa ser nesse formato, coloque apenas 1. Esse valor vai de 0 a 1, podendo ser .1, .2, .3...).

Comment: Esse dropdown é um <select>?

Comment: No primeiro comentário, ignore sobre o "float", eu achei que esse CSS era do menu todo, mas depois vi q era dos itens.